# why the subclass of NSMenu not responding?

Tags: cocoa, subclass, nsmenu

I created a menu resource in a separate xib file, made it to be a subclass NSMenu like the following, and the file's owner to be the StatusMenu

```
@interface StatusMenu : NSMenu
{
@private
    IBOutlet NSMenuItem *menuitem1;
    IBOutlet NSMenuItem *menuitem2;
}

- (IBAction)action1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)action2:(id)sender;
- (void)show;
@end
```

where show method is implemented in the following way

```
- (void)show
{
    NSImage *menuImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myicon" ofType:@"png"]];

    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setImage:menuImage];
    [statusItem setMenu:self];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}
```

Then I created and launched the StatusMenu instance in the app delegate like the following

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    statusMenu = [[StatusMenu alloc] init];
    statusMenu.user = self.user;
    [statusMenu show];
}
```

Now, I can see the icon on the status bar. But when I click on the icon, no responding is happening. What could be wrong?

Comment: There are quite a lot of things wrong with this. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Rob, what I want to achieve is clean code. I don't want to jam up all the menu handling code (action1, action2 etc) into my main AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually subclass `NSMenu` to do what you're trying to do.

You can simply create another class (call It `MenuController` or something), put It in your storyboard/xib and have an outlet to It in your `AppDelegate`.

[Here`s a sample project for you to check out](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/StatusItem%20Sample.zip).